# Preventing duplicate Blob objects in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb, dexie

Is there a built-in solution to prevent duplicate `Blob` objects within different records in `IndexedDB`?

Say I have this schema for a music store: `id, title, album, artwork`, and I wanted to add 2 songs from the same album to this store (so they most likely have the same artwork asset). Is there a *built-in* way to automatically store the artwork only once?

**What I've tried:**

- I tried to set a `unique` flag in `artwork` index, but after checking the size of the database before and after the insertion of the second song (using `chrome://settings/cookies`), the artwork is stored twice.
- I then tried to store the artworks in a separate store (with only `id` and `artwork` as a schema) with the same flag, but that didn't work too.

---

```
var database = new Dexie('TheDatabase');
database.version(1).stores({artworks: '++id, &artwork'});

var dbArt = database.artworks;

var artworkBlob = getBlob(image);
dbArt.put(artworkBlob);

//later:
dbArt.put(artworkBlob);
```

---

Am I misusing the `unique` flag in any way? Is it not supported in `Blob` objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though IndexedDB supports storing Blobs, it does not support indexing Blobs. Indexable properties can only be of type string, number, Date or Array<string | number | Date>. If not, IndexedDB will just silently ignore to index that particular object.

Also, in your sample code, you are not referring the artworks table, and you are trying to put the blob by itself instead of putting the document containing the blob property.

So what you could do instead, is to compute a hash / digest of the blob content and store as a string that you may index using a unique index.

```
var dbArt = new Dexie('TheDatabase');
dbArt.version(1).stores({
    artworks: `
        ++id,
        title,
        album,
        &artworkDigest` // & = unique index of the digest
});

var artworkBlob = getBlob(image); // get it somehow...

// Now, compute hash before trying to put blob into DB
computeHash(artworkBlob).then(artworkDigest => {

    // Put the blob along with it's uniqely indexed digest
    return dbArt.artworks.put({
        title: theTitle,
        album: theAlbum,
        artwork: artworkBlob,
        artworkDigest: artworkDigest
    });
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("Successfully stored the blob");
}).catch(error => {
    // Second time you try to store the same blob, you'll
    // end up here with a 'ConstraintError' since the digest
    // will be same and conflict the uniqueness constraint.
    console.error(`Failed to store the blob: ${error}`);
});

function computeHash (blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Convert to ArrayBuffer
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => resolve(filerReader.result);
        fileReader.onerror = () => reject(filerReader.error);
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    }).then (arrayBuffer => {
        // Compute Digest
        return crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", arrayBuffer);
    }).then (digest => {
        // Convert ArrayBuffer to string (to make it indexable)
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(
            null, new Uint8Array(digest));
    });
};
```

Side note: In IndexedDB 2.0, ArrayBuffers are indexable (but not Blobs still). However, I would never recommend to index such a large value in any database. Still better to index the digest.

Comment: I actually *did* implement a hashing method for storing the artworks in a separate store (using `SparkMD5`), but then I thought maybe I don't need it, taking advantage of the `IndexedDB` indexing and unique constrains. Didn't think `Blob`s might not be supported, though.

Comment: Yeah about my sample code, it was a code transfer mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I will follow your advice in storing `ArrayBuffer`s instead of `Blob`s.

Comment: While the idea is good, the performance is not. 
[`put`](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.put()) method does _**not work**_ as you likely suppose. You cannot use `put` as a one-liner to find a record by arbitrary indexed prop and update it with new props. `put` only searches by _**primary key**_ (as well as outbound key which is not the case). As `artworkDigest` is not a primary key, the above code should fail with the error: `Unable to add key to index: at least one key does not satisfy the uniqueness requirements`

Comment: @hindmost You're right - it is much better to have artworkDigest as primary key instead and get automatic replace of the existing value instead of getting ConstraintError when trying to put it. If ConstraintError is preferred, one could use add instead of put.

Comment: I also removed the recommendation to not using Blob because all browsers support it since many years now and it would increase performance when listing and searching items because Blobs are lazyloaded.